# Android/Eclipse Installation on Ubuntu 11.04 - aapt and adb not working properly

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I am a Linux n00b trying to setup my development environment in Eclipse. I have Eclipse and the Android SDK installed, but I am getting some errors when I start Eclipse or when I try to run ./aapt or ./adb.

```
jason@ubuntu:~/usr/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools$ ./aapt
./aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

jason@ubuntu:~/usr/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools$ ./adb
./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

That ELF class error makes me think I installed a wrong version of the software but I do not recall being asked to choose between x86 and x86-64.

```
jason@ubuntu:~/usr/android-sdk-linux_x86$ echo $MACHTYPE
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Are you sure you followed [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) guide completely? Do you have ia32-libs installed?
Try this:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: I did follow that guide completely but the package you referred me to fixed the problem. What is it exactly? Thank you!

Comment: Your base system is 64 bit, but the binary components distributed by google are 32-bit.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: The solution differs for Ubuntu >= 12.04. See answers from @Guy and Steven.

Answer (score 7):

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit and the above solutions don't quite work (I'm also using Andriod Studio but that shouldn't matter).  I guess the issue is that Google's ADK binary is a 32 bit application.  This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the Ubuntu version you running

If you running Ubuntu < 12.04 then run: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
(ia32-libs was deprecated in 12.04)

If you running Ubuntu >= 12.04 then run: `apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

To check your ubuntu version click on the cog icon in the top right corner and click "About this computer"

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone in the future trying to get Android build tools working. Ubuntu 15.04 required `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1`. `lib32ncurses5` may or may not be necessary, I haven't noticed any adverse affects without it.