# Unable to configure Android With Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I am new to Android and trying to setup Android Development Environment. I have followed the steps given in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) but I am still getting the error below:

> [2011-11-08 22:24:39 -
>   adb]/opt/eclipse/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
>
> [2011-11-08 22:24:39 - adb]'adb version' failed!
>   /opt/eclipse/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
>
> [2011-11-08 22:24:39 - adb]Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'

I have tried to resolve this issue by installing 3 times, but it still persists.
Could any one please help me to resolve this issue?

Looking forword for helping hands.

Environment Details :

> JDK : 7
>   Eclipse : 3.7.1
>   OS : Ubuntu 11.10

Thank you!

Anand Chavan

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Installing ia32-libs from the repositories will fix the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: This helped me out, thank you! I'm marking your answer as correct...in spirit.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out!
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I set it up

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=19446284&postcount=62

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't follow the instructions completely:

> 64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.
>   For information about how to add support for 32-bit applications, see
>   the **Ubuntu Linux installation notes**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds weird, but make sure that your Android SDK path has no spaces in it.  This is a known bug for the Windows version, and has produced similar errors to this, so it's worth trying.

Comment: The error contains the path, you can see that there are no spaces (`/opt/eclipse/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb`).

Comment: Possibly check out this answer, looks like a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056914/android-eclipse-installation-on-ubuntu-11-04-aapt-and-adb-not-working-properly