# opensuse 12.1 64bit - Android - error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1

Tags: android, 64-bit, opensuse, x86

I just installed eclipse, the android sdk and jdk on a fresh installation of opensuse 12.1, but by the time i create a new project i am getting the following error in the console:

[2012-04-05 14:11:05 TestingApp] /home/alex/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I know that i am using a 64bit machine and i need to install some 32bit drivers (keep finding the name 'ia32-libs' everywhere, but when i used >zypper install ia32-libs in the terminal, i get a no provider of 'ia32-libs' found.

Any help is more than welcome. I'm searching since yesterday :/

Comment: try [this][1] one please, you can find an naswer there


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056914/android-eclipse-installation-on-ubuntu-11-04-aapt-and-adb-not-working-properly

Comment: @AlexStyl Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same issue on openSUSE. The 32-bit runtime pattern thing didn't work.

Comment: I switched from openSUSE long time ago. I can't remember what I did for this issue I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps someone, I solved this error on openSUSE 12.2 (64bit) by installing:

```
sudo zypper install libstdc++47-32bit libzzip-0-13-32bit
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. I assume that there are some 32bit drivers missing. If you open YaST -> Software Management -> Patterns ... there is an entry with several 32bit drivers but I don't know WHICH of them I have to install in order to make android/eclipse work ... I assume that I don't have to install all of them ...?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue on opensuse 12.2.