# R.java is not being generated because eclipse cannot run aapt

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and eclipse for Android development. I used to keep the android-sdk in my home folder, but because of low space, I copied it to the hard disk. When I moved the sdk to the hard disk, I did not have permissions to run adb, aapt or other platform tools. So, I edited the /etc/fstab file and added the following line
`/dev/sda3       /media/hdisk ntfs-3g  defaults  0   0`
Now, when I execute the command `ls -l | grep "sdk"` in the terminal, i get this output

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 2012-10-20 16:07 android-sdk-linux

So, I have the permissions now, but when I run eclipse, the R.java file is still not generated, but the BuildConfig.java file is generated. I can run aapt from the terminal, but doing it every time I change the code is not practical. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems have to solved itself after restarting my PC about 2-3 times. Thanks for all the help everybody.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a 64bit Linux running, this command may help you:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Had the same issue and that one did the trick. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057134).

Answer (score 0):

Its a very basic check but have you changed the location of the Android SDK within Eclipse?
Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location

Comment: Yes, I've changed the location of the Android SDK in eclipse. I also haven't got any error messages in the console. So I'm assuming all configurations in eclipse are correct.